# Estoy intentando modificar el telefono de un cliente de la base de datos mediante un formulario con variables php

Tags: php

```
"UPDATE clientes (DNI_Cli,Nombre_Cli,Tfno_Cli) SET ('Tfno_Cli=$_POST['Tfno_Cli']') WHERE ('Tfno_Cli' = '$Tfno_Cli')
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error o problema con tu código actual?

Comment: Se un poco mas especifico con el error que estás teniendo, aunque por lo que veo el update deberia ser algo asi:  `"UPDATE clientes SET Tfno_Cli='".$_POST['Tfno_Cli']."' WHERE Tfno_Cli = '".$Tfno_Cli."';"`

Answer (score 0):

La mejor manera de hacer una consulta desde PHP es con queries preparadas de esta manera puedes evitar inyecciones SQL, podria quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
$query = "UPDATE clientes SET DNI_Cli = ?, Nombre_Cli = ?, Tfno_Cli = ? WHERE Tfno_Cli = ?";$stmt = $con->prepare($query);//Se prepara la consulta
$stmt->bind_params("isii",$DNI_Cli,$Nombre_Cli,$Tfno_Cli,$Tfno_Cli);//Se pasan los parametros
$stmt->execute();//Se ejecuta
$result = $stmt->affected_rows;//Se obtiene el numero de filas afectadas
if($result === 0){
    /*TODO*/
}
//Codigo en caso de que se haya actualizado
```

Puedes ver la referencia en [PHP MySQLi Prepared Statements Tutorial to Prevent SQL Injection](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection), un consejo es que en lugar de validar por telefono para modificar valides por DNI, es mas seguro.